# Can AWS Rekognition detect whether a face is real or a spoofed with no video analysis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm developing a facial recognition API with AWS Rekognition, and I need to check if the faces in the images uploaded by the user are real or fake. For instance, they could hold a phone with another person's face or a printed photo. I'd like to know if pure image analysis (no video) with Rekognition can provide me that answer.

I know there are other options like OpenCV, but I'd prefer to keep all the analysis in Rekognition if that's possible.

Comment: I guess you have to train your model to do that. 

Comment: Not trivially--without 3D info a good photo would be indistinguishable from reality. You might try to detect "unusual" pixel-level artifacts (might work for a photo on a phone, but not an actual photo) or reflections etc that wouldn't (likely) be present on a real face though.